# Are there true arithmetical statements that corresponds to inconsistency of inconsistent theories?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Lets take Naive set theory "NvST" which is the theory whose axioms are all instances of naive unrestricted comprehension, which is of course known to be inconsistent. So $\neg$ Con(NvST) is a TRUE statement!

> Question is there a TRUE arithmetical statement that corresponds to $\neg$ Con(NvST)?

The problem I'm getting is that since NvST is inconsistent, then it cannot be interpreted in PA + $\omega$-rule. So how can we get a sentence that can speak about the consistency status of that theory in the language of arithmetic if the theory itself cannot be interpreted in that language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gödel's work shows us how to write down an arithmetical statement that corresponds to $\operatorname{Con}(T)$ or $\neg\operatorname{Con}(T)$ for **any** theory $T$, as long as the set of axioms of $T$ is Turing-recognizable.

This works purely syntactically, and does not depend in any way of having an *interpretation* of the language of $T$ in mind. So you can certainly apply it to your naive set theory, since it is easy to recognize instances of unrestricted comprehension.

Since it is certainly the case that NvST is inconsistent -- you can prove a contradiction in just a handful of lines! -- the arithmetical statement $\neg\operatorname{Con}({\sf NvST})$ is certainly true in $\mathbb N$.

---

Where interpretability in $T$ comes into play is if we need something like $\operatorname{Con}(T)$ to be a $T$-statement rather than an arithmetical statement. This need arises on the way to the incompleteness theorem. And even then, what matters is that we can interpret a certain amount of arithmetic in $T$, not that we can interpret $T$ in the metatheory.

But we don't need to go there if all we want is to speak *about* provability in $T$ with arithmetical statements.

Comment: Although this is definitely an answer to my question [that's why I've accepted it] yet it did it by veering away from semantics to syntactical methods. Although that is sufficient, yet one would really want to know how that translates in term of semantics.

Comment: @Zuhair: The way I'm used to using the terms, "consistent" is a syntactic concept in the first place; it means that it is not possible to prove a contradiction from the axioms. In classical propositional or first-order logic, the consistent theories happen to be the same ones as the _satisfiable_ theories, which are the ones that have a model, but _a priori_ they are different concepts. I don't know of a natural way to express semantic satisfiability as a (first-order) arithmetical statement without using syntactic properties as a proxy.

Comment: But there is a syntactical-semantic equivalence with first order theories, this means that any syntactical argument can be equivalently phrased in semantic terms. There must be a semantic counter-part of the syntactical argument you've illustrated above. It's that what I would like to see.